# Problems with Post req (NodeJs/Express) - sending an empty object?

Tags: node.js, express, http, post, request

I am having some issues with a Post request. I am trying to post a js object, the http request works but it doesnt seems to get the values form the input fields, it posts instead an empty object! I have tried everything cant seems to find the error!

**app.js**

```
function addPoem() {
  event.preventDefault();
  let title = document.getElementById("titleInput").value;
  let author = document.getElementById("authorInput").value;
  let text = document.getElementById("textInput").value;

  let newPoem = {
    id: 8,
    title: title,
    author: author,
    text: text,
  };
  makeRequest("/poems/", "post", newPoem);
}

async function makeRequest(url, reqMethod, body) {
  const response = await fetch(url, {
    //headers = { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
    method: reqMethod,
    body: JSON.stringify(body),
  });
  console.log(response);
  const data = await response.json();
  console.log(data);
}
```

**index.html**

```
<form method="post" action="/poems">
   <h1>Send us your poem!</h1>
   <input type="text" requirede name="title" id="titleInput"> <br>
   <input type="text" required name="author" id="authorInput"> <br>
   <br> 
   <input type="text" required name="text" id="textInput" style="width:500px;height:500px">
   <br>
   <button type="submit" onclick="addPoem()">Send</button>
</form>
```

**server.js**

```
// Post a poem
app.post("/poems", (req, res, next) => {
  allPoems.push(req.body);
  res.json({ status: "A new poem has been posted!" });
});
```

Comment: How do you handle json body on the server? Using `body-parser`? Please show the connection code `body-parser` if you use it.

Comment: const express = require('express'); //
const { poems } = require('./Poems/poemsArray');  //
const app = express();  //
const port = 8080;  //
const allPoems = require('./Poems/poemsArray') //

app.use(express.json())  //
app.use("/", express.static('public'))  //

I dont use body-parser because thank to one of the latest updates, it has been included in express.json, if I am not incorrect...?

Comment: Please do not insert new code in comments, add it to your question instead. Have you tried specifying `content-type` as `application/json`? In your code, you commented out this header.

Answer (score 0):

I think your method should work, because you post directly from the server.js method

But if you yang to use the function in app.js use this

form method="post" action="/poems"
To
form method="post"  onsubmit="addPoem()"